# I can't retrieve responseText from servlet using AJAX

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, servlets

I have a servlet file called `NewServlet.java`. This servlet is called by my AJAX script to retrieve the response.

I have verified the servlet by testing it in a browser.

But when I call it from my AJAX script it gives me a blank `responseText` and an error that says

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://localhost:8084/WebApplication1/NewServlet.
>   Origin null is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin

**NewServlet.java**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class NewServlet extends HttpServlet {


    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();


        out.println("<option value='1'>one</option>");
        out.println("<option value='2'>two</option>");
        out.println("<option value='3'>three</option>");
        out.println("<option value='4'>four</option>");
        out.println("<option value='5'>five</option>");
        out.close();
    }


    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }


    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }


    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }

}
```

**test.html**

```
<html>

<head>
    <script language = "javascript">
        var xmlDoc = 0;
        var xhttp = 0;
        function reciveData()
        {

            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
            {
                xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else // IE 5/6
            {
                xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = redirectUser;        
            xhttp.open("GET","http://localhost:8084/WebApplication1/NewServlet",true);
            xhttp.send();
            }

        function redirectUser()
        {
            if (xhttp.readyState == 4)
            {
                log = 0;
                xmlDoc = xhttp.responseText;
                alert(xmlDoc);
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="reciveData()">

</body>
</html>
```

Can some one point me in a right direction ?

Thanks.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest#Cross-domain_requests is the problem you are having.

Comment: @andyb  Thanks, that was quite helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's on the browser side...the security model only allows AJAX requests to the same host/port that you fetched the page from.  Make sure that you've fetched your page via the server (e.g. http://localhost:8084/test.html) and not loaded it via the filesystem.  Then you should be good to go...or at least continue debugging. ;)

Comment: I'm sorry, but what do you mean by `loaded it via the filesystem` ? How do I check if I am not loading it through file system?

Comment: Your `test.html` page must be served by a server on the same domain as the server you are making the AJAX call to. So just put the .html file in your servlet container instead of using a local copy from the filesystem.

Answer (score 4):

This can indeed happen when the servlet runs on a different port than where the ajax request is coming from. This violates the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) for ajax requests and thus the browser won't process the ajax response. Apart from hosting the servlet behind the same port, other solutions are to return [JSONP](http://bob.pythonmac.org/archives/2005/12/05/remote-json-jsonp/) instead or to let the servlet set the [HTTP `Access-Control`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTTP_access_control) headers.

```
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

You however need to keep in mind that this way your servlet is by Ajax accessible to **everyone**. If the servlet returns sensitive information, then this is a security hole. But if it does not and it is supposed to be a *public* webservice, then it's safe.

Answer (score 2):

in my experience, if you want to load data with ajax, send your request to a jsp file, and get your response text from that jsp file. it is a lot easier to handel. see this example if you like

> > EDITED<<

==========================
ajax_load.js :

```
    var xmlhttp;

    function loadAdminRight(category){

    xmlhttp = GetXmlHttpObject();
    if (xmlhttp == null) {
        alert("Your browser does not support Ajax HTTP");
        return;
    }
    var url = "load.jsp";

    url = url + "?category="+category;
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = getLoad;
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send(null);


   }


    function getLoad(){
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
        document.getElementById("right_content").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                //or what you want to do
    }
}
```

===========================
load.jsp :

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<%

String l_category = request.getParameter("category");

if(l_category.equals("article")){
        out.write("You have choosen article category");
        out.write("<br/>");
    }

}else if(l_category.equals("news")){
        out.write("You have choosen article category");
        out.write("<br/>");
            }
%>
```

and to make the ajax going you just need to call the .js function from where you want, for example on a button click action : 
onClick="loadAdminRight("article");"

and you can import your java classes in a jsp file with adding <%page import="" %> to the top of your jsp page for example :

<%@page import="com.omicc.classes.Article"%>

write your own load.jsp file which handles the response, then use out.write in your jsp file to write the response text.

i wish it helps you

Comment: Can you give me an jsp example?

Answer (score 2):

```
This will solve your issue..
// Ajax response

res.setContentType("text/javascript");
res.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
res.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();
out.print("GRANTED");
out.close();
```